# Broken pipe error on scp

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I can ssh into my ubuntu box just fine, and I have already `scp`'d a version of my app onto the server, but when I run

`scp MaryBaked.tar.gz root@marybakedpdx.com:/home/marybakedpdx`

or even

`scp MaryBaked.tar.gz root@marybakedpdx.com:~`

The progress of the scp jumps up to 81%, then the process says `stalled` and I get

> rite failed: Broken pipe
>   lost connection

**EDIT**

> root@marybakedpdx:/home/marybakedpdx# df -T

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      ext4      30830588 2906508  26334944  10% /
none           tmpfs            4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs    498088       4    498084   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       101788     356    101432   1% /run
none           tmpfs         5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs       508940       0    508940   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs       102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
```

Comment: Is it 81% everytime?

Comment: it's either 77% or 81%

Comment: Can you put the output of `df -T` into your question. I suspect it could be out of disk space.

Comment: added above..formatting is off

Comment: Take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/what-does-the-broken-pipe-message-mean-in-an-ssh-session

Comment: I had already added `echo "ServerAliveInterval 60"` to my ~/.ssh/config file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76837/discussion-between-redress-and-martin-konecny).

Comment: I was getting the following error 

$ scp -rp /home/myhome/gitlab/test/ account@x1win:Work/

scp: Work//test/Lib/utility/templates: set times: Broken pipe

Problem was the "-p" option I was using.
When I took out the -p, the error went away.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try throttling  - `2Mb/sec max throughput` like so:

```
scp -l 2000 MaryBaked.tar.gz root@marybakedpdx.com:/home/marybakedpdx
```

Many times, broken pipes are caused by scp pushing/pulling too fast for something in the stack that throttling can resolve.

[scp man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Answer (score 13):

It happened to me when I copied a file that has been already opened on my local computer and it was busy.

Comment: That was indeed the case for me. Why can't the error message say that?

Comment: that would be nice. Probably, the system can't figure out remotely what is wrong with the file, there is no adequate messaging.

Comment: This happens when the file is locked on the local machine. Good error messages are so important!

Answer (score 12):

**The problem** is that the connection closed, probably because the file is too big and the session is terminated by timeout.

**Solution 1**: Sending back and forth keep alive messages from the server (acks) which keeps the session, Using **ServerAliveCountMax** and **ServerAliveInterval** options

```
scp -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 <yourIP>:~
```

In this example, every 15 seconds looking back for acks and if 3 acks in 45 seconds (15*3) not coming back close the session.

Look at the properties documentation below :

> **ServerAliveCountMax**
> Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may be sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the server. If this threshold is reached while server alive messages are being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, terminating the session. It is important to note that the use of server alive messages is very different from
> TCPKeepAlive (below). The server alive messages are sent through the encrypted channel and therefore will not be spoofable. The TCP
> keepalive option enabled by TCPKeepAlive is spoofable. The server
> alive mechanism is valuable when the client or server depend on
> knowing when a connection has become unresponsive. The default value
> is 3. If, for example, ServerAliveInterval (see below) is set to 15
> and ServerAliveCountMax is left at the default, if the server becomes
> unresponsive, ssh will disconnect after approximately 45 seconds.
>
> **ServerAliveInterval** Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if
> no data has been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message
> through the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.
> The default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
> the server.

**Solution 2**:
I can suggest you a simple workaround: **compress the file , send it and extract it in your destination machine.** This will short the connection time and should fix the timeout issue.

```
gzip bigfile.bin
scp bigfile.bin.gz <destinationIp>:~/
ssh -At <destinationIp>
cd ~
gunzip bigfile.bin.gz
```

Comment: solution 2 - gzip the file is a good workaround

Comment: My file is already gzipped, and those ssh options do not seem to help :(

Comment: I had to crank ServerAliveCountMax up to 10 for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my Mac, if I set the -l flag on SCP and set a low data rate it would work. Eventually, I disabled "Jumbo Frames", which solved my problem.

Comment: how did u disable the Jumbo frames? can you give the command?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was that the file was opened in another app.