# `client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` error during pull from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

[image]

I got these errors from bitbucket when I'm pulling the latest changes of bitbucket via ssh

we have many files in our repository and I got these issues when I’m fetching the latest changes and all branches

Comment: [Related, but not solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66934945/1256452)

Comment: [Related, with possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52415943/1256452)

Comment: [Related, points to IPv6 as the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65689280/1256452)

Comment: [Related: something was trying to use jumbo frames inappropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30020519/1256452)

Comment: You will find these by searching for "client_loop: send disconnect: broken pipe" with google or stack overflow search. There are many more.